# How to enable the content editor as a droppable target with jQuery-ui?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, jquery-ui

I'm trying to enable the WordPress content editor as a droppable using jQuery UI drag and drop. However, I can't get the drag to drop, or the drop event to fire.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
<ul id="keywords">
    <li>drag one</li>
    <li>drag two</li>
    <li>drag three</li>
</ul>

jQuery("#keywords").find("li").each(function(){jQuery(this).draggable(
{ 
    helper:'clone', 
    start: function(event, ui){
        jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);}, 
        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 1); 
            } 
        });
    });

jQuery('#content').droppable(
{ 
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        alert('dropped in content'); //DOES NOT FIRE!!!
        jQuery(this).dropIt(ui.draggable.html());
    } 
});

if(typeof tinyMCE=='object')
{ 
    alert('tinyMCE is active'); //DOES NOT FIRE!!!
    jQuery('#editorcontainer').droppable(
    { 
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        { 
        alert('dropped in tinyMCE editor'); //DOES NOT FIRE!!!
        //Dynamically add content
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'New content.');
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: TinyMce doesn't use `#content`, that's hidden away in the background so to speak, TinyMCE creates a frame where content is managed, which is then later sent(or inserted) into the original textarea. @cheesypeanut has you covered.

Comment: Why isn't your jQuery fired on document ready? If you're firing before that, TinyMCE hasn't done it's thing yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example the following line:

```
jQuery(".myDiv").find("li").each(function(){
```

should be:

```
jQuery(".keywords").find("li").each(function(){
```

That should enable the list items to be dragged and dropped.

To allow the items to be dropped on the TinyMCE textarea the following code works.

```
$('#editorcontainer').droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
        alert('dropped'); //NOW FIRES!
        //Dynamically add content
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'New content.');
    } 
});
```

Comment: That was just an input error when I created the question. I've changed it, but that's not the problem. Still no drop event fires.

Comment: Try the solution that I've added above.

Comment: it certainly makes sense, but at least in my test sites (running wordpress 3.2.1), I cannot get the drop alert to fire. +1 anyway. I've reposted my code if you or anyone else sees what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare on TinyMCE body's  tag like this, it works for me

On tiny_mce_src.js

```
t.iframeHTML += '</head><body ondrop="parent.drop(event);"  " id="' + bi + '" class="mceContentBody '+ t.id +'_cl' + bc +'" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get(\'' + t.id + '\').onLoad.dispatch();"><br></body></html>';
```

On editor's  page:

```
    function drop(ev)
    {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',true,data);
    }
    function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
            var html = $('#'+ev.target.id).html();
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",html);
    }
```

It's seems using jquery with TinyMCE doesn't work ...